# 2011 macbook pro blue screen

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, memory

I'm trying to determine whether I'm having a ram, drive, or board issue. I used to be able to log in and actually use my laptop but it would run slow and over little time the fan would kick on and freeze up or the screen would show multiple lines or have a blue screen. But Now it won't even go to the log in screen and right when I turn my laptop comes on it has lines running through the screen with the apple logo then it will hang there for a while and go to a blue screen with multiple lines running through it. I hope this is no expensive fix I was thinking it's a possible ram issue due to how slow it started runnin but could be a possible drive issue as well but when I hold down the option key and select either bootcamp or the backup it will blue screen. It wouldn't let me do anything after the latest update it started doing this. I hope someone answers this soon I'm lost without making music. Thankyou all for any future input

Comment: did you run the Apple Hardware test ?

Comment: sorry to say but you might be a part of this problem reported here http://breakfree.cc/

Comment: dead graphics card? run in Safe mode if you can to see!

Comment: Yeah those pictures are exactly what my mac is doing.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you a part of wide problem for your model as reported elsewhere.

[2011 Macbook Pro Graphics Card Defect](http://breakfree.cc/)

In some cases Apple will replace your logic board free of charge even if it is out of warranty, but that you need to discuss with them.

[Take Action](http://action.mbp2011.com/)